# how to send data to other paticipant using intent or bundle in android

Tags: android, multiplayer, google-play-games

Hi friend, am trying to play game service example i.e "buttonclicker",
what I want to do is, send the current time to other participants on invitation  buttonclick ,in this example startActivityForResult(intent,requestcode) & another with 3 parameters startActivityForResult(intent,requestcode,bundle), 
here I face the problems;

case1:
I have tried the 2nd method with 3 parameter which contain the my current time in bundle, but when i run that example it through error

code of it:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent;


        Bundle BundleTimer = new Bundle();
        BundleTimer.putString("StartTime",millisecond);

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_single_player:
            case R.id.button_single_player_2:
                resetGameVars();
                startGame(false);
                break;
            case R.id.button_sign_in:
                // user wants to sign in
                if (!verifyPlaceholderIdsReplaced())
                {
                    showAlert("Error", "Sample not set up correctly. Please see README.");
                    return;
                }
                beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
                break;
            case R.id.button_sign_out:
                signOut();
                switchToScreen(R.id.screen_sign_in);
                break;
            case R.id.button_invite_players:
                // show list of invitable players
                intent = getGamesClient().getSelectPlayersIntent(1, 3);

                switchToScreen(R.id.screen_wait);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS, BundleTimer);
                break;
            case R.id.button_see_invitations:
                // show list of pending invitations
                intent = getGamesClient().getInvitationInboxIntent();

                switchToScreen(R.id.screen_wait);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RC_INVITATION_INBOX, BundleTimer);
                break;
            case R.id.button_accept_popup_invitation:
                // user wants to accept the invitation shown on the invitation
                // popup
                // (the one we got through the OnInvitationReceivedListener).
                acceptInviteToRoom(mIncomingInvitationId);
                mIncomingInvitationId = null;
                break;
        }
    }
```

logcat for case1:

```
> 08-30 19:26:28.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13846): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 08-30 19:26:28.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13846):
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> com.example1.playservicedemo1.multiplayer.startActivityForResult 08-30
> 19:26:28.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13846):    at
> com.example1.playservicedemo1.multiplayer.onClick(multiplayer.java:215)
> 08-30 19:26:28.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13846):  at
> android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485) 08-30 19:26:28.687:
> E/AndroidRuntime(13846):  at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080) 08-30 19:26:28.687:
> E/AndroidRuntime(13846):  at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 08-30
> 19:26:28.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13846):    at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 08-30
> 19:26:28.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13846):    at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 08-30 19:26:28.687:
> E/AndroidRuntime(13846):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 08-30
> 19:26:28.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13846):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-30
> 19:26:28.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13846):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 08-30 19:26:28.687:
> E/AndroidRuntime(13846):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
> 08-30 19:26:28.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13846):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 08-30
> 19:26:28.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13846):    at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

case2:
here i tried to send data with intent, using intent.putextra("statrtime",millisecond)
but when i try to retrive this extra value in other app running the same example code,
it through nullpointer on getextra from the intent;

code of it

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent;


        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_single_player:
            case R.id.button_single_player_2:
                resetGameVars();
                startGame(false);
                break;
            case R.id.button_sign_in:
                // user wants to sign in
                if (!verifyPlaceholderIdsReplaced())
                {
                    showAlert("Error", "Sample not set up correctly. Please see README.");
                    return;
                }
                beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
                break;
            case R.id.button_sign_out:
                signOut();
                switchToScreen(R.id.screen_sign_in);
                break;
            case R.id.button_invite_players:
                // show list of invitable players
                intent = getGamesClient().getSelectPlayersIntent(1, 3);
                intent.putExtra("StartTime", millisecond);
                switchToScreen(R.id.screen_wait);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS);
                break;
            case R.id.button_see_invitations:
                // show list of pending invitations
                intent = getGamesClient().getInvitationInboxIntent();
                intent.putExtra("StartTime", millisecond);
                switchToScreen(R.id.screen_wait);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RC_INVITATION_INBOX);
                break;
            case R.id.button_accept_popup_invitation:
                // user wants to accept the invitation shown on the invitation
                // popup
                // (the one we got through the OnInvitationReceivedListener).
                acceptInviteToRoom(mIncomingInvitationId);
                mIncomingInvitationId = null;
                break;
        }
    }
```

logcat for case2:

```
> 08-30 19:01:46.264: E/AndroidRuntime(25770):
> java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message 08-30
> 19:01:46.264: E/AndroidRuntime(25770):    at
> android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method) 08-30 19:01:46.264:
> E/AndroidRuntime(25770):  at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:159) 08-30
> 19:01:46.264: E/AndroidRuntime(25770):    at
> com.example1.playservicedemo1.multiplayer.onInvitationReceived(multiplayer.java:573)
> 08-30 19:01:46.264: E/AndroidRuntime(25770):  at
> com.google.android.gms.internal.bj$n.a(Unknown Source) 08-30
> 19:01:46.264: E/AndroidRuntime(25770):    at
> com.google.android.gms.internal.bj$n.a(Unknown Source) 08-30
> 19:01:46.264: E/AndroidRuntime(25770):    at
> com.google.android.gms.internal.p$b.p(Unknown Source) 08-30
> 19:01:46.264: E/AndroidRuntime(25770):    at
> com.google.android.gms.internal.p$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
> 08-30 19:01:46.264: E/AndroidRuntime(25770):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 08-30
> 19:01:46.264: E/AndroidRuntime(25770):    at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 08-30 19:01:46.264:
> E/AndroidRuntime(25770):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 08-30
> 19:01:46.264: E/AndroidRuntime(25770):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-30
> 19:01:46.264: E/AndroidRuntime(25770):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 08-30 19:01:46.264:
> E/AndroidRuntime(25770):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
> 08-30 19:01:46.264: E/AndroidRuntime(25770):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 08-30
> 19:01:46.264: E/AndroidRuntime(25770):    at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

in this example i want to send time duration to selected players so that if they not response after that time they are not to play for that request, if they response withen that period of time then they are allowed to play the game,

friends i am stuck on this, please suggest how to get this done,
sorry for the bad english,
thank you

Comment: Wait you want to send data from one device running your app to another device?

Comment: YES EXCATLY I WANT SEND DATA FROM 1 APP TO ANOTHER WHEN I SELECTS THE MULTIPLAYER

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with intents. To communicate between different phones you need to use something that can connect the devices together. This can be a web server, Bluetooth, a local wifi network but there has to be a connection between the different phones before you can do this.

Comment: yes ,but its a game play service which create connection through startactivityfor result, how to deal with it using game play service

Comment: I don't understand why it matters that's its a game play service. You just can't send intents over a network to other devices. That's pretty much it. You need to rework how your app is set up.